# Negation after the to-infinitive

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation, infinitives

Do the following sentences mean the same?

> He seems **to have not eaten** for ages.
>
> He does not seem **to have eaten** for ages.

Comment: Here is another possible variant: "He seems not to have eaten for ages."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me the first implies there exists evidence that no eating has taken place: He is extremely skinny, showing the signs of starvation and malnurishment, etc.

The second implies that there is lack of evidence of him eating: There is no food in the fridge, no dirty dishes, no crumbs, no food scraps in the trash, etc.

Logically both come to the same conclusion with a slightly different nuance.

Comment: Nicely put! It might be worth pointing out that besides that *tiny* difference of nuance depending on whether the negation applies to ***to seem*** or ***to have eaten***, the latter could also be negated as *He seems **not** to have eaten for ages*.  I don't think it makes one iota of difference whether ***not*** goes before ***to have*** or ***eaten***. There's also *He seems to **not** have eaten for ages*, which I'd say is syntactically "valid", but not "idiomatic" in this exact context (though it would be okay in structurally similar contexts).

Comment: Or even 'He seems to have eaten not for ages' for a bit of an archaic twist